# Python line working on Mac but not on AWS Windows Server Instance, can different operating systems result in different code being ran?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, amazon-ec2

I am running the below command perfectly fine in on my Mac, but in EC2 AWS Windows server 2016 this same line of code is not working. What could be the reason?

```
permanent = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)\
           .sort_values('id')\
           .drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

error I am getting on windows 2016 server, running the same line:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I running 2.7 on mac and 3.6 python on Windows server.

Comment: *I running 2.7 on mac and 3.6 python on Windows server. * Then yes, if you're running two distinctly different versions of Python, the same code can work on one and fail on the other. It has nothing to do with the OS; it has everything to do with Python 2.7 and 3.x not being the same.

Comment: crap, what would be the equalivent for the code in 3.6?

Comment: That's not the question you asked in this post.

Comment: Thanks I will repost another questions

Comment: even if versioning is different, why would the library change?

Comment: The Python documentation explains the compatibility issues. Did you try reading them? The docs on 3.x speak clearly on what those differences are and what changes are breaking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert below line of code from python 2.7 to python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036024/how-to-convert-below-line-of-code-from-python-2-7-to-python-3-6)